# AWS Lambda C# CloudFormation config

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I try to make a simple lambda function with C# and deploy it with CloudFoundation

I have this config:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
    "Description" : "My PoC.",

    "Resources": {
        "MyPocLambda": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Description": "Just a lambda for a Hello world",
            "Properties": {
                "Runtime": "dotnetcore1.0",
                "FunctionName": "HandleGet",
                "Handler": "MyPoc::MyPoc.Function::HandleGet",
                "MemorySize": 256,
                "Timeout": 30,
                "Role": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaExecutionRole", "Arn"]},
                "Code": {
                    "ZipFile": "./bin/Release/netcoreapp1.0/MyPoc.zip"
                }
            }
        },
        "LambdaExecutionRole": {
          "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
          "Properties": {
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [{
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": { "Service": ["lambda.amazonaws.com"] },
                "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole"]
              }]
            },
            "ManagedPolicyArns": ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"]
          }
        }
    }
}
```

The deployment does not work because of the code property. What am I supposed to do with it in C#?

Thanks

Comment: You should enclose the text of your C# code in the ZipFile property. Alternatively, you could upload your code to an S3 bucket and use the bucket url instead of ZipFile as the value of Code property.

Answer (score 0):

A notation.  I'm fairly sure you can't use this process to deploy dotnetcore1.0, or any runtime other than node.js using the zipfile property of Code.  There are 2 options I am aware of.

1. Deploy using the dotnet cli available from Visual Studio 2015 SP3/2017. This would be:

dotnet lambda deploy-function

When using this cli call, You should make sure to have your aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json file in the project set up with something similar to the following:

```
{ 
  "Information" : [ some information ],
  "profile":"YourDefaultProfile",
  "region" : "us-east-1",
  "configuration" : "Release",
  "framework" : "netcoreapp1.0",
  "function-runtime":"dotnetcore1.0",
  "function-memory-size" : 256,
  "function-timeout" : 30,
  "function-handler" : "AWSLambdas::AWSLambdas.Function::FunctionHandler"
}
```

This would be executed in the folder where you have your project file and resources; not the bin folder.  You can also specify additional parameters such as role, etc. to shorten the prompting beyond this default cli call for deployment.  There is also a cli help line for this call:

dotnet lambda help

2. There is the ability to use SAM to deploy the Lambda; Serverless Application Model made available near the end of 2016.  Example CloudFormation deployments are on the AWS website:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/deploying-lambda-apps.html

Good luck!